# Select2: add option from the search field

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, jquery-select2

I wonder if somebody can help me with this, i have a select tag with some predefined options, now what I want is when i search an non existing option in the select2 search field, to create an option with that inserted search value.

eg. when i type four which does not exist in my options, to actually create an option with a value four. I hope i explained my problem well.

```
<select name='selectized' id='selectized' class='form-control'>
    <option value='1'>one</option>
    <option value='2'>two</option>
    <option value='3'>three</option>
</select>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#selectized').select2({
            placeholder: 'sometext',
            allowClear: false
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `tags: true` as [this](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#tags) example showing

```
$('#selectized').select2({
      placeholder: 'sometext',
      allowClear: false,
      tags: true
});
```

```js
$('#selectized').select2({
  placeholder: 'sometext',
  allowClear: false,
  tags: true
});
```

```css
#selectized {
  width: 200px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<select name='selectized' id='selectized' class='form-control'>
   <option value='1'>one</option>
   <option value='2'>two</option>
   <option value='3'>three</option>
</select>
```